# ASP.NET Multiple sitemaps and breadcrumb

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitemap, breadcrumbs

I have Web.sitemap, admin.sitemap, user.sitemap.
I put in web.config the 3 providers.

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="SiteMapDefault">
  <providers>
    <add
      name="SiteMapDefault"
      type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" />
    <add
      name="SiteMapUser"
      type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapFile="user.sitemap" />
    <add
      name="SiteMapAdmin"
      type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
      siteMapFile="admin.sitemap" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

My breadcrumb is in the masterpage :

```
<b>You are here: </b>
    <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server">
    </asp:SiteMapPath>
```

It's currently working with the SiteMapDefault.
What I would like to do is changing the breadcrumb when I'm on the Admin or User pages.
Admin > Link 1 > Link 1.1

I also have 3 files :
SiteMap.aspx (the default one visible on the website), SiteMapAdmin.aspx and SiteMapUser.aspx.

So I have my normal breadcrumb working and when I'm going on /Admin, I would like the breadcrumb to use admin.sitemap instead of Web.sitemap.
How can I do that ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your `Page_PreInit` event, you can set the `SiteMapProvider` of each of the SiteMap driven controls by name to override the default.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapUser";
    this.Menu1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapUser";
}
```

Comment: I wrote `protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapDefault";

}` on the main masterpage called base.master (Class App_Master_base). I wanted to try your solution but it can't recognize the variable SiteMapPath1. So I declared it in the App_Master_base class but I haven't found how to access to this variable.    I tried with  `this.Master.Master.SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapUser";` because my user.master is using a threecol.master which is using base.master

Comment: Read [this article](http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx) to learn how to expose public properties on a master base class. The key is to set the `<%@ MasterType TypeName="MasterPageBase" %>` declaration on the pages so you can access those properties of the master page, including setting values to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you NightOwl888.
I can't with the MasterType method. I tried with FindControl(...) too but it doesn't work.
So I resolved it doing this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.ToString().IndexOf("user") != -1)
    {
        SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapUser";

    }
    else if (Page.ToString().IndexOf("admin") != -1)
    {
        SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapAdmin";
    }
    else
    {
        SiteMapPath1.SiteMapProvider = "SiteMapDefault";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work on the Page_PreInit so I put this on the Page_Load in the masterPage that contains the SiteMapPath1.
You helped me a lot, thank you.

This is a noob solution that corresponds to my directory tree.